Muxing H264 packets into a MPEGTS container using libav*
I'm writing a C++ program where I need to encode packets in h264 format and mux them to a MPEG TS container. For the encoding part, I based my code on the encode_video example (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_video_8c-example.html#a9) provided in FFMPEG documentation, and it seems to work fine. In particular, I generate a std::vector of packets which I sequentially write to an output .ts file for debug. Such .ts file plays fine with SMPlayer, and a ffproba command gives
>> ffprobe  -print_format json -show_format -show_streams out.ts
Input #0, h264, from 'out.ts':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/50",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480,
            "coded_width": 640,
            "coded_height": 480,
            "has_b_frames": 1,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "4:3",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 30,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "field_order": "progressive",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "false",
            "nal_length_size": "0",
            "r_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "time_base": "1/1200000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "out.ts",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "h264",
        "format_long_name": "raw H.264 video",
        "size": "435443",
        "probe_score": 51
    }
}


The dts and pts timestamps are also set.
However, if I try to mux them in MPEG TS format, using as a base the example mux.c (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/mux_8c-example.html), it doesn't work. A shortened version of my muxing code is as follows: (the variables ending with "_" are class fields)
int MyProcessing::Mux(const std::string outputFilename) {
    AVFormatContext *muxingContest;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&muxingContest, NULL, NULL, m_output.c_str());

    auto outFormat = muxingContest->oformat;
    outFormat->video_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;

    AVStream *outStream;
    const AVCodec *codec;

    Mux_AddStream(&outStream, muxingContest, &codec, outFormat->video_codec);

    AVDictionary *opt = nullptr;
    Mux_OpenVideo(muxingContest, codec, outStream, opt);
 
    if (!(muxingContest->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
      avio_open(&muxingContest->pb, m_output.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    }
    avformat_write_header(muxingContest, &opt);

    auto muxOk = true;
    size_t countMuxedFrames = 0;
    while ((muxOk) && (countMuxedFrames < packets_.size())) {
        muxOk = !MuxPacket(muxingContest, outStream, packets_[countMuxedFrames], &opt);
        countMuxedFrames++;
    }

    av_write_trailer(muxingContest);
    if (!(muxCodecContextPtr_->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) avio_closep(&muxingContest->pb);
 
    return 0;
}


int MyProcessing::Mux_AddStream(AVStream **stream, AVFormatContext *format, const AVCodec **codec, enum AVCodecID codecId) {
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecId);
    muxPacketTmpPtr_ = av_packet_alloc();
    *stream = avformat_new_stream(format, *codec);
    (*stream)->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };
    (*stream)->id = format->nb_streams-1;
    (*stream)->index = 0;
    muxCodecContextPtr_ = avcodec_alloc_context3(*codec);
    Mux_FillCodecContext(*muxCodecContextPtr_, codecId, **stream);
    if (format->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        muxCodecContextPtr_->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    return 0;
}


void MyProcessing::Mux_FillCodecContext(AVCodecContext &cc, enum AVCodecID codecId, AVStream &stream) {
    cc.codec_id = codecId;
    cc.bit_rate = 400000;
    cc.width    = outputWidth_;
    cc.height   = outputHeight_;
    cc.time_base  = stream.time_base;
    cc.gop_size = 10;
    cc.max_b_frames = 1;
    cc.gop_size      = 12;
    cc.pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    if (cc.codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) cc.max_b_frames = 2;
    if (cc.codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO)  cc.mb_decision = 2;
    av_opt_set(&cc, "preset", "slow", 0);
    av_opt_set(&cc, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
}


int MyProcessing::Mux_OpenVideo(AVFormatContext *format, const AVCodec *codec, AVStream *stream, AVDictionary *opt_arg) {
    AVDictionary *opt = nullptr;
    av_dict_copy(&opt, opt_arg, 0);
    muxCodecContextPtr_->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    avcodec_open2(muxCodecContextPtr_, codec, &opt);
    av_dict_free(&opt);
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, muxCodecContextPtr_);
    return 0;
}

int MyProcessing::MuxPacket(AVFormatContext *format, AVStream *stream, AVPacket &pkt, AVDictionary **opt) {
    AVBitStreamFilterContext *bsf = av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb");
    AVPacket filteredPkt = pkt;
    auto filterResult = av_bitstream_filter_filter(bsf, format->streams[stream->index]->codec, NULL,
                                         &filteredPkt.data, &filteredPkt.size,
                                         pkt.data, pkt.size,
                                         pkt.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY);

    if (filterResult < 0) return filterResult;
    else {
        filteredPkt.buf = av_buffer_create(filteredPkt.data, filteredPkt.size,
                                       av_buffer_default_free, NULL, 0);
    }
    av_bitstream_filter_close(bsf);
    filteredPkt.stream_index = stream->index;
    filteredPkt.dts = filteredPkt.pts;
    filteredPkt.duration = ((double)stream->time_base.num / (double)stream->time_base.den) / STREAM_FRAME_RATE;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&filteredPkt, muxCodecContextPtr_->time_base, stream->time_base); // rescale output packet timestamp values from codec to stream timebase
    auto writePktResult = av_write_frame(format, &filteredPkt);
   // auto writePktResult = av_interleaved_write_frame(format, &filteredPkt);
    return 0;
}


The console error is
[mpegts @ 0x55555736edc0] H.264 bitstream malformed, no startcode found, use the video bitstream filter 'h264_mp4toannexb' to fix it ('-bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb' option with ffmpeg)

It Is telling me to apply the h264_mp4toannexb filter. As you see from the code, I've put the filtering accordingly, but the error message persists (unless I'm applying the filter in a wrong way).
In the last lines of method MuxPacket(), if I uncomment the line with av_interleaved_write_frame() and comment the previous one, I get the same error, as well as a seg fault. Inspecting with GDB, the call stack for the seg fault is as follows:
#0  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:440
#1  0x00007ffff67c7cb6 in av_packet_copy_props () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58
#2  0x00007ffff67c8447 in av_packet_ref () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58
#3  0x00007ffff7e2fa13 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58
#4  0x00007ffff7e2fb11 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58
#5  0x00007ffff7e30575 in av_interleaved_write_frame () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58

I tried to look at solutions online, but they are either old or they don't work. Some of the things I tried and didn't work:

Putting the line

muxCodecContextPtr_->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

in Mux() after the call to avformat_alloc_output_context2.

Setting

packet.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

before the call to av_write_frame / av_interleaved_write_frame.

Trying to write by hand to the file the starting code as described here Need to convert h264 stream from annex-b format to AVCC format.

Playing with parameters in Mux_FillCodecContext().



"H.264 bitstream malformed, no startcode found"  You must check if your H.264 packet has valid bytes data for that function. Did you check on Google about what is an H264 "start code" anyway? This means: check your packet (it is an array of bytes, so it is just an array of numbers), check IF the first three array slots (0-2) hold 0 , 0 , 1 in order, IF NOT then also check IF the first 4 slots (0-3) hold 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 in that order. If any of those two sequences exists then your H264 is valid so far and something else must be the problem...

Also I suggest you make an H264 file from some test image using command line FFMpeg, then try to mux that h264 data using your code. Since FFmpeg will output a  valid H264 file, this allows you to test your code with a correct data.structure. It is possible there is nothing wrong with your code and you are just giving it bad/incorrect file input...

PS: I did not downvote. Just passin through and sharing some advice..
